# Disable a PHP Plugin on mobile Screens with Code?

Tags: php

I have this plugin called "WP FLOAT", I want to disable it when it detects a small screen size, lets say smaller than 400px.  Is there a line of PHP code I can paste in one of the plugin's files to make this happen?

These are the only files for the plugin:

wp-float/wp-float(.)php

wp-float/readme(.)txt

wp-float/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified(.)js

wp-float/js/jquery.easing(.)js

wp-float/js/wp-float-button(.)js

wp-float/js/jquery.floater.2.2(.)js

wp-float/js/button-wpfloat(.)php

What would I paste and in which file? Thanks

Comment: `wp float` seems to be a wordpress plugin. Are you using it in a wordpress site and if so, what version of wordpress? Or do you have a non-wordpress site? Please also tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As Nicolas said, there's no way to access the client screen size on server side unless we have previously sent that information from the client side, JavaScript for example.

But, headers brings us a nice information. So, if you're looking to disable it for, let's say, mobile devices, which we can assume they won't have a big screen, you can try reading the headers of the request to get the browser's agent, lets say, in PHP:

```
if (preg_match('/iphone|android|blackberry|nokia/i'),$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    echo "Looks like a small screen device...";
```

You could also try this PHP class for detecting mobile devices:
http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Later you can do something like this

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    echo "It's a phone or tablet";
}

if($detect->isTablet()){
    echo "It's a tablet";
}

if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()) {
    echo "It's a phone ;)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can remove properly with jquery after you get the current size of screen or with media querys in css.

Comment: Um, Sorry not sure what you mean. So you would modify a current plugin file with Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, because PHP is on the server, there is no way to get the size of the screen from it.

However, you could use javascript to redirect to the current page and disable the plugin:

```
if(!isset( $_GET['r'] ) )     
{
  $script = "<script>";
  $script .= 'document.location="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?r=1&width=screen.width';
  $script .= "</script>";
  echo $script;
}     
else {
  if( isset( $_GET['width'] ) && $_GET['width'] < 400 )
    // Disable plugin
}
```

I would suggest you to change the plugin or look for another workaround, because I believe this is gonna be a little slow.

Comment: Oh hmmm. Im just surprised there is not a way of just pasting a php line into the plugin files, cause there are plugins that I thought are responsive.  Ill have to search around

Comment: They may be responsive, but always use, either CSS Media Queries to adjust the design or Javascript to do it dinamically.

Comment: Oh, so CSS Media Queries is the best way to do it, but it must be pretty advanced I guess?

Comment: Not really, because Media queries will not disable the plugin, but you could modify it to fit many screen widths. I think it's a little advanced, but nothing too complicated (PHP is much harder than CSS - Well, CSS is not a programming or scripting language).

By the way, **tim's** answer is the more accurate IMHO.